# Beginner: how to start with contributing for ubuntu

Tags: application-development

Can I take part in some project for ubuntu? What should i do? I am new, and i would love to complete or take part or start a project for it.

Thx

Comment: You can start by asking questions here about Ubuntu problems or applications. Later on you can start answering new users questions based on your own experiences. Later you can start writing and sharing scripts.